# Android Studio 3.0 Preview missing 'use the same device for future launch' checkbox

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device, android-studio-3.0

I faced a bug with Android Studio 3.0 Preview. When I plug the device, small useful checkbox is missing.

[image: Screenshot]

Does anybody know how to enable it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had the same issue. You need to disable instant run in your android studio settings, follow below steps:

- Open the Settings or Preferences dialog.
- Navigate to Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run
- Uncheck the box next to Enable Instant Run

After that you will have this option and if you will enable instant run again android studio will remember your selected device

Comment: "Uncheck the box next to Enable Instant Run" is greyed out in studio 3. can someone help ? I am solving some other problem and disabling the instant run is the solution for this problem.

Comment: There is no "Instant Run" option.

Comment: @doctorram I would recommend update to Android Studio 3.5, in this version device selection menu has changed and this problem not exist anymore.

Comment: @PawełDedio I am using Android Studio 3.5 and I still don't see such an option.

Answer (score 4):

Other possibilities for AS 3.0 (limited to your current project AFAICS):

- Select the `Use same device for future launches` option in your project through `Run -> Edit Configurations... -> General -> Deployment Target Options -> Use same device for future launches` (`Target` should be set to `Open Select Deployment Target Dialog`).
- In the same menu as above, select `Emulator` from `Target` and then choose your preferred AVD through `Prefer Android Virtual Device`.

Comment: You mean `Run -> Edit Configurations...`?

Comment: @user905686: Good catch!  You're absolutely correct.  In my "youthful exuberance" I forgot part of the path...  Added correction.